# sed works properly in SSH, not in PHP

Tags: php, ssh, sed

So, I have the following line that I run in PHP with exec($addPHPtags);

```
$addPHPtags = "/bin/sed -i '/<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">/ a\ <?php \n ?> '" . $instance['file'] . " 2>&1";
```

I'd expect that command to find the key  and append it with a php tag. However, when I run it in PHP, I get the following error if I trap command output:

```
[0] => /bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown command: `?'
```

However, if I run the same command in SSH, it works completely fine:

```
/bin/sed -i '/<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">/ a\ <?php \n ?>' file.php
```

I'm out of ideas, I've tried various alternatives but to no avail. Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/bin/sed/ -i '/<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">/ a\ <?php \n ?> 'INPUTFILE` 2>&1
```

Notice that a space is lacking between the regex and your input file.

```
$addPHPtags = "/bin/sed -i '/<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">/ a\ <?php \n ?> '" . $instance['file'] . " 2>&1";
#                                                                       ^^
```

Put a space there in your PHP, and I think it might be ok... and double-escape the newline. Why aren't you doing the transform directly in PHP?

Comment: Great, I've had to double escape the linebreak and the issue was the lacking space. Silly - really. Thanks for the great help !

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know why it's not being done in PHP with something clever around preg_replace?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to double escape the newline. Try:

```
$addPHPtags = "/bin/sed -i '/<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">/ a\ <?php \\n ?> '" . $instance['file'] . " 2>&1";
```

Comment: Double escaping the linebreak fixes (or not?) the error but instead shows a different one:
  
[0] => /bin/sed: no input files